# How can add style for google map icon

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I have a google map, and i wont to add some style for icon.

I will create icon like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position:           new google.maps.LatLng(mapinfo[index][6], mapinfo[index][7]),

icon: {
url : '<? bloginfo('url'); ?>' + img_src  + '',
scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
},

map:                    map,

scrollwheel:        false,

streetViewControl:true,

title:              $title

});
```

Here, the icon display like this:

[image]

I need to add some style by css or jquery to show this icone like this:

[image]

Comment: Add the white background to the actual image?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. You have an icon and you want to place it in Google Maps.. but what is not working here?

Comment: @putvande i mean i need to add some css style to icon, i have many of icon in one map, and i need to add some style

Answer (score 0):

Maybe styling isn't the answere here. You could create the marker with the white margin yourself and afterwards use this page to create the rest:
[Google Map Custom Marker Maker](http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php)